# Always show zero value in sum dynamic field name

Tags: javascript

I have several fields generated dynamicaly like shown below:

```
cols += '<td><input type="text" id="total" name="field[total][' + counter + ']" placeholder="Total" onchange="findTotal()"></td>';
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function findTotal(){
    var sum = 0;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName('field[total][]');
    for (var i = 0; i < cost.length; i++)
    {
        sum += parseFloat(cost[total][i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('totalsemua').value = sum;
}
```

I am trying to calculate the sum but the value always shows 0, I don't understand, please help me.

Comment: have you checked what you're getting in cost variable ?

Comment: @CodeManiac sorry i use wrong method hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are trying to do

```
sum += parseFloat(cost[total][i].value);
```

but what is `cost[total][i].value`?

```
var cost = document.getElementsByName('field[total][]');
```

is a list of elements (NodeList), so values should be inside `cost[i].value`, not `cost[total][i].value`.

Also you're using `document.getElementsByName` incorrectly:

```
var cost = document.getElementsByName('field[total][]');
```

but the argument should be an *element name* (not element with "name" attribute with that value). See the difference:

```
<someElement>...</someElement><!-- element with name someElement -->
<div name="someName">...</div><!-- element with name div and with attribute "name" -->
```

The method is designed to find `<someElement>` things: `document.getElementsByName('someElement')`. Either use `document.querySelectorAll` with a proper selector or `document.getElementsByName('input')` and filter it properly.

Comment: cost var cost field[total][] is a name of my input field (ex: field[total][0]), and i want to increment with loop the spesific field, and i try cost[i].value still show 0

Comment: @NewbsWantGeeks I've edited the post to clarify further: each element has a name (like `div` or `img`) and some elements may have a `name` attribute. The `document.getElementsByName` is for element names, not `name` attritubes.

Comment: ohh i understand in my case i want to select element with name not element name thank you for your help

Comment: @NewbsWantGeeks actually, you are using attributes in a rather inconvenient manner: you complicate it with some original syntax to set a value inside the attribute value. I'd suggest to use something like `index="' +counter+ '"` instead. If you really need `name`, you can generate it elsehow.

Comment: ok i will try to use queryselector all for my name atrribute hehe thank you

Comment: @NewbsWantGeeks for attribute selectors, refer to something like https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_attribute_selectors.asp, but don't mix the square brackets for their syntax with those you use. Like I wrote, with your current syntax it may be a little complicated

Comment: if i change my attribute name to total[] will reduce complicated ??

Comment: @NewbsWantGeeks well, you can try creating a selector which works for you and decide for yourself. I personally wouldn't use `[` or `]` inside attribute values